What is the difference of adding an audiobook to iTunes or Books app?
What is the difference of adding an audiobook to iTunes or Books app ?
As far as I can see, adding to iTunes (Music) I can find (easily) the file location with "Show in Finder" context menu.
But adding to Books I can not find the file location any more. I can't figure out why Book design it this way.
I remember for the old version of Music I can set media kind to other than music. But now (probably since MacOS 14) I can only set it to music.


There are some significant differences between the old iTunes and the Books app that replaced it for audiobooks. From the standpoint of file management and editing, the switch from iTunes to Books was all loss and no gain for the user. Books pretty much offers no control. For example, you cannot change/fix the title or author of an audiobook in Books.
To address your specific questions:
If you import an MP3 audiobook into Books, it ends up in a subfolder within the following folder:
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books/Audiobooks
(At least that's true in Sonoma.)
Each subfolder in that folder contains a different audiobook but they have useless titles so you just have to dig around to find the one you're interested in. Knowing where the files are doesn't help you modify them, however, since you can't do that in Books.
You asked why Apple does things this way. I would say it is because Apple wants users to purchase audiobooks from Apple and is not interested in supporting any other options for acquiring audiobooks or managing them.
If you do want to modify the MP3 files of an audiobook in any way, here's what you can do:

Import the MP3s into the Music app.
Make all the changes you want, much like you used to in iTunes. Try to make sure it's all perfect before going further, because things work best if you get them right the first time.
Open the folder where your now-edited MP3 audiobook files live. Unlike the Books app, the Music app does let you show the files in Finder, so this is easy.
Import the now-edited MP3s into the Books app. (This copies the files and places them in a subfolder in that folder location I pointed out above.)
If something still isn't the way you want it in Books, delete the audiobook from Books and keep making edits in Music and then re-import into Books. This doesn't always work perfectly so it's best to try to get it right the first time, however.
Once you're sure the audiobook is showing up the way you want in Books, you can then delete the no-longer-needed files that are in your Music app. Don't just drag the folder to the Trash in Finder; use the Music app to keep your Music library clean.

One last point: You don't need to worry about specifying the media type of the MP3s. Music can open any MP3 and will treat it as a music file. Books treats any MP3 you import as an audiobook.

But what is the point of add them into Books then?

The point of adding them into Books is so that you can listen to them. The only real difference between an audiobook and another sound file is that you are unlikely to listen to an entire audiobook without pausing. What Books does that Music does not is remember where you were when you paused so you can resume listening at the place you left off.

Thanks for pointing that out. I find if I switch to another audiobook and switch back, iTunes won't remember where I stop. Why iTune won't remember that?! I t looks like a bug to me. But anyway, maybe you can add that your answer then it will be a complete answer.

That's a problem on your end. iTunes can remember your place even if you switch among multiple audiobooks.

Well, through my test, iTunes can remember where I was when I paused but didn't switch to other song or audiobook, so I can continue my listening later.
